# Pandas Symmetric Difference a list value between 2 columns

Tags: pandas

I've a following dataframe, df:

```
                     A                   B
 0  [ACL1, ACL2, ACL3]  [ACL1, ACL4, ACL2]
```

I want to perform a symmetric_difference on the A and B list so that the output will be [ACL3,ACL4]

```
df1 = df['A'].symmetric_difference(df['B'])
print (df1)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'symmetric_difference'
```

But it give an above error....Did I did wrongly? How can I accomplish the final output?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `symmetric_difference` is a method of [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), instead you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[['ACL1', 'ACL2', 'ACL3'], ['ACL1', 'ACL4', 'ACL2']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B'])


def symmetric_difference(x):
    return list(set(x.A).symmetric_difference(x.B))


result = df[['A', 'B']].apply(symmetric_difference, axis=1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    [ACL3, ACL4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Daniel...I upgraded Pandas and it works.....  But how do I get the "Device" name reflect on the same rows as the output? 0    [ACL3, ACL4]
1              []
2    [ACL6, ACL7]
dtype: object

Comment: You can add `df[['A', 'B']].apply(symmetric_difference, axis=1)` as a new column to your dataframe.

Comment: You make my day!!....df['DIFF'] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(symmetric_difference, axis=1) is good enough for me...

Comment: @Michael Glad I could help! If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If do care about the performance

```
[list(set(x).symmetric_difference(set(y))) for x , y in zip (df.A,df.B)]
[['ACL3', 'ACL4']]
```